# Finding Boost C++ version

Tags: gcc, boost, version

How to find which gcc version the installed boost library is using ? So I can find which version of C++, my HPX library is using. HPX library depend on boost library hugely. I actually forgot how I (using which version of gcc) built boost library a year ago.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's layout verioned when you built boost, the lib name must like: `libboost_wave-gcc48-mt-s-1_65.a`, so `gcc48` (gcc 4.8.x) is your version.

**More accurate : Run following command**:

`strings libboost_wave-gcc48-mt-s-1_65.a | egrep -ie "GCC.*([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])"`

You'll get the exact gcc version `4.8.5` from the output:

`GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)`

Comment: Quanmao - Thank you. What's mean by Layout verioned ?

Comment: Oh, typo, sorry, "version". It just means when building the boost library, we often use command like `--layout=versioned`  in build command:  `./bjam install --prefix=/mylibs/boost_1_65_0 address-model=64 toolset=gcc --layout=versioned --without-python --build-type=complete link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static variant=release`

Comment: Quanmao - Thanks !